# Uni project fprfixture generator in Python

Tags: python

```
teams = [
    ("Team 1", "Town 1", "Stadium St1"),
    ("Team 2", "Town 1", "Stadium St2"),
    ("Team 3", "Town 2", "Stadium St3"),
    ("Team 4", "Town 2", "Stadium St4"),
    ("Team 5", "Town 3", "Stadium St5"),
    ("Team 6", "Town 3", "Stadium St6"),
    ("Team 7", "Town 4", "Stadium St7"),
    ("Team 8", "Town 4", "Stadium St8"),
    ("Team 9", "Town 5", "Stadium St9"),
    ("Team 10", "Town 5", "Stadium St10"),
]
```

In ABC premier league, there are 10 teams. You have been hired to build a program that will generate
fixtures for these teams based on the following given rules.

1. A team must play every other team twice, i.e. in their home stadium and away stadium. At some point, teams from the same local town will have to play each other, these teams should only meet after they have played teams from other local towns.
2. Only 4 teams can play in a given weekend, for example Team1 vs Team3 and Team10 vs Team8.
3. While developing the fixtures, indicate the local town, stadium, leg (i.e. 1 or 2) and the weekend (indicate as weekend #1, weekend #2 etc.) the teams are meant to meet.

I am having difficult time. This is what I wrote in Python so far

```
import itertools

def generate_fixtures(teams):
    fixtures = []
    weeks = 1

    while weeks <= len(teams) - 1:
        week_fixtures = []
        
        # Generate fixtures for teams from different towns
        for pair in itertools.combinations(teams, 2):
            if pair[0][1] != pair[1][1] and pair[0][0] not in week_fixtures and pair[1][0] not in week_fixtures:
                fixture = f"Week {weeks}: {pair[0][0]} vs {pair[1][0]} (Leg 1, {pair[0][2]})"
                week_fixtures.extend([pair[0][0], pair[1][0]])
                fixtures.append(fixture)
                if len(week_fixtures) == 2:
                    break
        
        # Generate fixtures for teams from the same town
        for town in set(team[1] for team in teams):
            teams_in_town = [team for team in teams if team[1] == town]
            for pair in itertools.combinations(teams_in_town, 2):
                if pair[0][0] not in week_fixtures and pair[1][0] not in week_fixtures:
                    fixture = f"Week {weeks}: {pair[0][0]} vs {pair[1][0]} (Leg 2, {pair[0][2]})"
                    week_fixtures.extend([pair[0][0], pair[1][0]])
                    fixtures.append(fixture)
                    if len(week_fixtures) == 2:
                        break
        
        weeks += 1

    return fixtures

# Define teams
teams = [
    ("Team 1", "Town 1", "Stadium St1"),
    ("Team 2", "Town 1", "Stadium St2"),
    ("Team 3", "Town 2", "Stadium St3"),
    ("Team 4", "Town 2", "Stadium St4"),
    ("Team 5", "Town 3", "Stadium St5"),
    ("Team 6", "Town 3", "Stadium St6"),
    ("Team 7", "Town 4", "Stadium St7"),
    ("Team 8", "Town 4", "Stadium St8"),
    ("Team 9", "Town 5", "Stadium St9"),
    ("Team 10", "Town 5", "Stadium St10"),
]

fixtures = generate_fixtures(teams)

# Print fixtures
for fixture in fixtures:
    print(fixture)
```

Comment: Please read [mre]. The above is missing information: what do you get from that script and what do you expect instead? In other words you need to define very precisely `I am having a difficult time`: What is your exact problem? What is the part of the script you don't understand? ... Without more details, this is basically a `please do my homework/fix my code` question which is off topic.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this solves the problem but the output is very well predicted (fixtures aren't created "randomly"):

```
import itertools
import random

def generate_fixtures(teams):
    fixtures1 = []
    fixtures2 = []
    deffered1 = []
    deffered2 = []
    
    for t1,t2 in itertools.combinations(teams, 2):
        m1 = (t1[0],t2[0],1,t1[2])
        m2 = (t1[0],t2[0],2,t2[2])
        target1 = fixtures1 if t1[1]!=t2[1] else deffered1
        target2 = fixtures2 if t1[1]!=t2[1] else deffered2
        target1.append(m1)
        target2.append(m2)
            
    random.shuffle(fixtures1)
    random.shuffle(fixtures2)
    random.shuffle(deffered1)
    random.shuffle(deffered2)
    
    return [f'Week {(i//2)+1}: {m[0]} vs {m[1]} (Leg {m[2]}, {m[3]})' for i,m in enumerate(fixtures1+fixtures2+deffered1+deffered2)]

# Define teams
teams = [
    ("Team 1", "Town 1", "Stadium St1"),
    ("Team 2", "Town 1", "Stadium St2"),
    ("Team 3", "Town 2", "Stadium St3"),
    ("Team 4", "Town 2", "Stadium St4"),
    ("Team 5", "Town 3", "Stadium St5"),
    ("Team 6", "Town 3", "Stadium St6"),
    ("Team 7", "Town 4", "Stadium St7"),
    ("Team 8", "Town 4", "Stadium St8"),
    ("Team 9", "Town 5", "Stadium St9"),
    ("Team 10", "Town 5", "Stadium St10"),
]

fixtures = generate_fixtures(teams)

# Print fixtures
for fixture in fixtures:
    print(fixture)
```

Comment: thank u so much this was a lot of help, but the problem is the fixtures are duplicating, how to get rid of that??, I want 2 different fixtures each week until all the fixtures are completed and teams from different towns should play each other first.

Comment: That's not part of the specification but you can either randomize fixtures and deffered matches, then join them and calculate week, or you can use permutations instead of combinationsto achieve the same result. Do I need to update the answer or can you do that yourself?

Comment: update it for me plzzz

Comment: @IssaOsman check the updated answer

Comment: @IssaOsman do you mind accepting the answer?